# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, plotly-dash

I have this issue with my code. I have a list of strings, `symbols`, that I pass as a parameter in my function,  `statsTable()` .

I'm using the `symbols` list in my SQL query to pull the requested items from my dB, in my case this list is a list of stocks. I would rather not use a loop here. The output of the function should create a DataFrame using data from my PostgreSQL dB.

Take a look below:

```
@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('table_stats', 'data'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('dynamic-dropdown', 'value')])

def statsTable(symbols):
    if symbols == None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    symbols = tuple(symbols)

    df = postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, f"SELECT id, companyname, marketcap, to_char(100.0*week52change,'999D99%'), week52high, week52low, to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%'), next_earnings_date, pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) FROM security_stats WHERE security_stats.id IS {symbols} ;", col)
    data = df.to_dict('rows')
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in security_stats.columns]
    return dt.DataTable(data=data, columns=columns)
```

I transform the list of stocks into a Tuple to remove the brackets so my SQL query doesn't get confused. When I run this code for my Dash app, I get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`.

I don't understand why because when I run the code below in a sandbox environment (to test if it works) everything seems fine, I get a DataFrame of the data that I'm asking for , without using a loop:

```
symbols = ('FB','AAPL', 'EBAY','AMD')
col = ['Symbol','Company','Market Cap','1yr-Change', '52-Week High','52-Week Low','Dividend Yield','Next Earnings Report','PE-Ratio','Beta']

df = postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, f"SELECT id, companyname, marketcap, to_char(100.0*week52change,'999D99%'), week52high, week52low, to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%'), next_earnings_date, pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) FROM security_stats WHERE security_stats.id IN {symbols} ;", col)
df.head()
```

This is the output I'm looking for...

[image: Dataframe]

If this helps, here is the function I use to pull the SQL data and transform it to a DataFrame:

```
def postgresql_to_dataframe(conn, select_query, column_names):
    """
    Tranform a SELECT query into a pandas dataframe
    """
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(select_query)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    
    # Naturally we get a list of tupples
    tupples = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    
    # We just need to turn it into a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(tupples, columns=column_names)
    return df
```

What is causing me to raise this error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_dict'` in my `statsTable(symbols)` function? I appreciate all the help I can get here, been struggling with this one.

EDIT:
This is the full error.

```
>>> data = df.to_dict('rows')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
In particular, give us the *entire* error message; then display and trace the offending values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    cursor.execute(select_query)
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print("Error: %s" % error)
    cursor.close()
    return 1
```

When the exception is raised, your exception handling causes `postgresql_to_dataframe` to return an integer rather than a DataFrame. It is, of course, not possible to call `.to_dict` on an integer, as the error message tells you quite explicitly.

So the proximate cause is that an exception is raised by the query execution. The Dash app is probably a context that doesn't allow you to see the standard output, so you aren't getting the error printout.

Comment: Thank you, this was the error. Do you happen to know a way how to structure my  SQL query so it doesn't need a loop? Im assuming the method I used caused the error.